# What to do if I am involved in a road accident between two border controls?

Tags: europe, driving, regulations, automobiles

If I travel from Hungary to Serbia, I have already passed the Hunagrian border control and then get involved in a road accident before entering Serbia (in the zone between the borders). Is this neutral territory? Should I call the Hungarian or the Serbian police?

Comment: Does such a zone really exist?

Comment: @gerrit there are 200-300 meter between the borders. And some drivers try to jump the queue there.

Comment: Is that really between the borders, or just between the border controls?

Comment: between the border controls

Comment: Somewhere between the two border posts will be the actual border. Which side you are on when the accident happened will determine which country the accident happened in, and which rules apply.

Comment: Can't you just fill in the international accident form and let the insurance companies figure it out?

Comment: @Andra AFAIK you always have to call the police

Comment: @Dirty-flow I don't know in this specific case, but it certainly isn't always the case. Where I live you can get the police quite annoyed if you involve them in an accident with only material (small) damages.

Comment: it makes difference if foreign cars are involved.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Without any relevant exception I can think of, there is no such thing as an "area between land borders". A land border between two countries follow in almost all cases a very well defined path and what you actually mean is the area between two border control posts.

If you e.g. locate the border crossing on E75 between Hungary and Serbia on [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?z=16&ll=46.175915,19.978904), you can see that the actual border is pretty much exactly in the middle between the checkpoints.

So, even if you travel from Hungary to Serbia on this road, have passed the Hungarian checkpoint and for immigration purposes technically left Hungary, you are still in Hungary until you cross the border.

Comment: while this may be true, how does it help the OP? Who should he call with his car accident?

Comment: It should answer his question because it explains why the assumption leading to his question is wrong. He is not "between two countries" but between two border checkpoints. Even there, it should be possible to find out in which country he is.

Answer (score 5):

In many places the area between the two sets of border guards is taken very seriously indeed and is under the control (the firm control) of one of both sets of guards.

Since the natural reaction to a car accident or even a stalled car is to get out, either to look at the damage or to talk to the other driver, do this first, with caution.

There is a good chance that someone will yell loudly at you not to get out of the car. Friends of mine had a car stall in the 10m or so between the US and Canada border, tried to get out to push it, and honestly thought they were going to be shot. By **Canadians**. Border zones are serious. If this happens to you, freeze. Optionally, get back in the car. Someone will approach you. Report the accident to that person and do what that person says.

If nothing particularly happens when you get out to do the usual car trouble things, feel free to call the police force of your choice and report the accident. Should there be some administrative reason why you need to call the other police force, or the border authorities, the worst that will happen is you need to make a second phone call.

Comment: You cannot extrapolate the North American situation to Europe. Border crossings in Europe are quite relax

Comment: Who deleted all the comments to this answer?